# Show that a function is increasing

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the following question:

Show that if *j* > 0, then the function *f (m)* = *(1 + j/m)<sup>m</sup>* is an increasing function of *m*.

Clearly, I have to derive the function and I obtain *f '(m)* = (j/m + 1)<sup>m</sup> [log(j/m + 1) - j/(m (j/m + 1))]

However, I can't see how to show that this is strictly positive, thanks for your help.

Comment: also, you should note that you are smoothing out what looks like a discrete function in order to take a derivative. This is fine, but deserves some words said about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: 
By the mean value theorem
$$
\log(1+x)=\frac{x}{1+c}
$$
for some $0<c<x$.

Additional hint:
$$
\frac{x}{1+c}>\frac{x}{1+x}
$$
for $c$ in this range.

Comment: Okay, I see that but I don't see how to use this to prove that the difference in the second term of the derivative is positive...

Comment: Do you see how what I wrote is related to the difference you have on the left hand side?

Comment: Yes, it's the same form, where c=j/m in the second term, right?

Comment: well $j/m$ is $x$ for me right? I will add an additional hint.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: certainly! good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way you started, you just need to keep slugging.  To show that $f'(m) > 0,$ it's enough to show that the stuff inside the brackets is $> 0$.  So you need $$\log \left(1+\frac{j}{m} \right)-\frac{j}{m+j}>0$$  If we write $x=j/m,$ then we need $$\log \left(1+x \right) - \frac{x}{1+x} > 0, \text {for }x>0.$$
This is straightforward.  The value is $0$ at $x=0$ and you can just take a derivative to see that it increases with $x.$